# React, Set.state() and issues with API calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

So I am trying to make an api call in react (for the first time and I'm unfamiliar with React) and it's not going so well. So what's happening below is that I pass a variable to the handlepony function, that then gets sent to my backend (in express) through an axios call. That is put into the url for the api string and then returns and sets ponyArray. All of this works quite fine. My console.log for "this is ponyArray inside handlepony " displays the return that I'm expecting.

Here is the problem. My this.state.ponyArray and this console.log are both returning undefined, and I cannot set them. It may be an asynchronicity issue or it may be that I am out of scope for the this value to call the constructor this properly. Here is the first piece of code I tried.

```
handlePony(feeling){

    console.log("inside App. and my feeling is ", feeling);

    this.setState({
      feeling: feeling,
      ponyArray: []
    }, function(){

        let ponyArray = this.state.ponyArray;

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/User/ponys', {
          feeling: this.state.feeling
        })
          .then(function(response){
            let jsonobj = JSON.parse(response.data.body)
            console.log("pony return ok ", jsonobj);
            let keyindex = 0;
            jsonobj.faces.forEach(function(face){

                ponyArray.unshift({
                  image: face.image,
                  key: keyindex
                });
                keyindex+=1;

            });
            console.log("this is ponyArray inside handlepony ", ponyArray);
            console.log("this 'this' after ponyArray", this);
          })
          .catch(function(error){
            console.error("error from pony", error);
          });
    });
  }
```

Alternatively, rather than doing the initial set state as a promise I tried to just set state after everything else finished. I had the same problem - console.log(this) returns undefined and the set state does not appear to run (the console logs do not even return). If it IS a scoping issue with this I would think I would have to somehow bind this to the axios.post method and I don't know how to do so (also it seems hacky).

```
handlePony(feeling){

    let ponyArray = [];

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/User/ponys', {
      feeling:feeling
    })
      .then(function(response){
        let jsonobj = JSON.parse(response.data.body);
        console.log('pony returned ok ', jsonobj);
        let keyindex = 0;
        jsonobj.faces.forEach(function(face){

            ponyArray.unshift({
              image: face.image,
              key: keyindex
            });
            keyindex+=1;

        });

        console.log('this', this);

        this.setState({
          ponyArray: ponyArray
        }, function(){
            console.log('ponyArray', ponyArray);
            console.log('this.state.ponyArray', this.state.ponyArray);
        });

      })
      .catch(function(error){
          console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Any help that could be given would be much appreciated. It seems strange that I am facing this much difficulty on what I thought was supposed to be a trivial ajax api call. I think I know at a handwavey high level what the issue is (maybe), so any code snippets that could be provided would be the most useful. Thanks!

PS If it helps I've included hastebins.

Example 1: https://hastebin.com/ewoyupuvon.js

Example 2: https://hastebin.com/vuroqeniyu.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` needs to be bound to your React Component. Right now, `this` is bound to the Axio object. Use an `arrow` to fix this `.then((response) =>`

```
handlePony(feeling){

    let ponyArray = [];

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/User/ponys', {
      feeling:feeling
    })

      .then((response) => { // Arrow function to bind this with your Component

        let jsonobj = JSON.parse(response.data.body);
        console.log('pony returned ok ', jsonobj);
        let keyindex = 0;
        jsonobj.faces.forEach(function(face){

            ponyArray.unshift({
              image: face.image,
              key: keyindex
            });
            keyindex+=1;

        });

        console.log('this', this);

        this.setState({
          ponyArray: ponyArray
        }, function(){
            console.log('ponyArray', ponyArray);
            console.log('this.state.ponyArray', this.state.ponyArray);
        });

      })
      .catch(function(error){
          console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

you can also use `.bind(this));` or :

```
let ponyArray = [];
const self = this;

self.setState({})
self.state.ponyArray
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just mutate `ponyArray` (your first solution) as react won't know about the change and it wouldn't rerender.

Use the second solution + arrow functions to keep the same value of `this`:

```
.then(response => {
  // ...
})
```